# HTML table to array PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, html-table

I have a schoolcalendar online, but I want to have it in my own application.
Unfortunately I can't get it working with PHP and regex.

The problem is that the table cells are not divided equally and that it changes per class.
You can find the schedule [here](http://cibap.nl/beheer/modules/roosters/create_rooster.php?element=CR13A&soort=klas&week=37&jaar=2012) and [here](http://cibap.nl/beheer/modules/roosters/create_rooster.php?element=CR02B&soort=klas&week=37&jaar=2012).

The regex I tried is this:

```
<td rowspan='(?:[0-9]{1,3})' class='value'>(.+?)<br/>(.+?)<br/>(.+?)<br/><br/><br/></td>
```

But it does not work correctly!

The end array must look something like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => maandag //the day
        [1] => 1 //lesson period
        [2] => MEN, 16, dm //content of the cell
    )
```

I hope that this question is clear enough, because I'm not an English ;)

Comment: If you *really* need to parse HTML use an HTML parser.

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: @xvilo let me know if you have any questions about my answer at all, hope it helps :)

Comment: @pebbl Yes it was WONDERFULL! i'm soooo happy right now :D :D :D now my schedule appliction works :P - http://beta.xvilo.net/rooster - it is dutch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex matching table rows in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289181/regex-matching-table-rows-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good luck with this one, it's going to be tricky... just 'using a HTML parser' isn't actually going to avoid the major problem, which is the nature of a table that uses rowspans. Although whilst it is always good advice to use a HTML Parser for parsing large amounts of HTML, if you can break that HTML down into smaller, reliable chunks - then parsing using other techniques is always going to be more optimal *(but obviously more prone to subtle unexpected differences in the HTML)*.

### Normalise the table

If it were me I'd start with something that can detect where your table starts and ends *(as I wouldn't want to parse the entire page even when using a HTML Parser if I don't need to)*:

```
$table = $start = $end = false;
/// 'Vrijdag' should be unique enough, but will fail if it appears elsewhere
$pos = strpos($html, 'Vrijdag');
/// find your start and end based on reliable tags
if ( $pos !== false ) {
  $start = stripos($html, '<tr>', $pos);
  if ( $start !== false ) {
    $end = stripos($html, '</table>', $start);
  }
}

if ( $start !== false && $end !== false ) {
  /// we can now grab our table $html;
  $table = substr($html, $start, $end - $start);
}
```

Then due to the haphazard way the cells are spanned vertically *(but seem to be uniform horizontally)* I would choose a 'day' column and work downwards.

```
if ( $table ) {
  /// break apart based on rows
  $rows = preg_split('#</tr>#i', $table);
  ///
  foreach ( $rows as $key => $row ) {
    $rows[$key] = preg_split('#</td>#i', $row);
  }
}
```

The above should give you something like:

```
array (
  '0' => array (
    '0' => "<td class='heading'>1",
    '1' => "<td rowspan='1' class='empty'>"
    '2' => "<td rowspan='5' class='value'>3D<br/>009<br/>Hk<br/><br/><br/>"
    ...
  ),
  '0' => array (
    '0' => "<td class='heading'>2",
    '1' => "<td rowspan='2' class='empty'>"
    '2' => "<td rowspan='3' class='value'>Hk<br/>"
    ...
  ),
)
```

Now that you have that, you can scan across each row, and where you preg_match a rowspan, you'd have to create a copy of that cell's information into the row below *(in the right place)* so as to actually create a complete table structure *(without rowspans)*.

```
/// can't use foreach here because we want to modify the array within the loop
$lof = count($rows);
for ( $rkey=0; $rkey<$lof; $rkey++ ) {
  /// pull out the row
  $row = $rows[$rkey];
  foreach ( $row as $ckey => $cell ) {
    if ( preg_match('/ rowspan=.([0-9]+)./', $cell, $regs) ) {
      $rowspan = (int) $regs[1];
      if ( $rowspan > 1 ) {
        /// there was a gotcha here, I realised afterwards i was constructing
        /// a replacement pattern that looked like this '$14$2'. Which meant
        /// the system tried to find a group at offset 14. To get around this
        /// problem, PHP allows the group reference numbers to be wraped with {}.
        /// so we now get the value of '$1' and '$2' inserted around a literal number
        $newcell = preg_replace('/( rowspan=.)[0-9]+(.)/', '${1}'.($rowspan-1).'${2}', $cell);
        array_splice( $rows[$rkey+1], $ckey, $newcell );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above should normalise the table so that the rowspans are no longer a problem.

*(Please note the above is theoretical code, I've manually typed it and have yet to test it -- which I will be doing so shortly)*

### After testing

There were a few little bugs with the above that I have updated, namely getting php's arguments for certain functions round the wrong way... After sorting those it seems to work:

```
/// grab the html
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.cibap.nl/beheer/modules/roosters/create_rooster.php?element=CR13A&soort=klas&week=37&jaar=2012');

/// start with nothing
$table = $start = $end = false;
/// 'Vrijdag' should be unique enough, but will fail if it appears elsewhere
$pos = strpos($html, 'Vrijdag');

/// find your start and end based on reliable tags
if ( $pos !== false ) {
  $start = stripos($html, '<tr>', $pos);
  if ( $start !== false ) {
    $end = stripos($html, '</table>', $start);
  }
}

/// make sure we have a start and end
if ( $start !== false && $end !== false ) {
  /// we can now grab our table $html;
  $table = substr($html, $start, $end - $start);
  /// convert brs to something that wont be removed by strip_tags
  $table = preg_replace('#<br ?/>#i', "\n", $table);
}

if ( $table ) {
  /// break apart based on rows (a close tr is quite reliable to find)
  $rows = preg_split('#</tr>#i', $table);
  /// break apart the cells (a close td is quite reliable to find)
  foreach ( $rows as $key => $row ) {
    $rows[$key] = preg_split('#</td>#i', $row);
  }
}
else {
  /// create so we avoid errors
  $rows = array();
}

/// changed this here from a foreach to a for because it seems
/// foreach was working from a copy of $rows and so any modifications
/// we made to $rows while the loop was happening were ignored.
$lof = count($rows);
for ( $rkey=0; $rkey<$lof; $rkey++ ) {
  /// pull out the row
  $row = $rows[$rkey];
  /// step each cell in the row
  foreach ( $row as $ckey => $cell ) {
    /// pull out our rowspan value
    if ( preg_match('/ rowspan=.([0-9]+)./', $cell, $regs) ) {
      /// if rowspan is greater than one (i.e. spread across multirows)
      $rowspan = (int) $regs[1];
      if ( $rowspan > 1 ) {
        /// then copy this cell into the next row down, but decrease it's rowspan
        /// so that when we find it in the next row we know how many more times
        /// it should span down.
        $newcell = preg_replace('/( rowspan=.)([0-9]+)(.)/', '${1}'.($rowspan-1).'${3}', $cell);
        array_splice( $rows[$rkey+1], $ckey, 0, $newcell );
      }
    }
  }
}

/// now finally step the normalised table and get rid of the unwanted tags 
/// that remain at the same time split our values in to something more useful
foreach ( $rows as $rkey => $row ) {
  foreach ( $row as $ckey => $cell ) {
    $rows[$rkey][$ckey] = preg_split('/\n+/',trim(strip_tags( $cell )));
  }
}

echo '<xmp>';
print_r($rows);
echo '</xmp>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use a HTML parser to extract the values. PHP Simple HTML parser is worth a shot:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/