# If row contains string, remove entire row

Tags: jquery, regex, html-table, removechild

Exactly as the title says, I'm trying to remove the entire row of a table if a match occurs. I have the following:

```
$('tr > td:nth-child(3)').text().match(/\$/g);
```

So in this case, if the third column contains a '$', I would want the entire row to be removed. I'm not sure how to go about this since the above only returns an array with a length of the number of matches and each index is the matched string.

Pseudo:

```
if($('tr > td:nth-child(3)').text().match(/\$/g)){
    $(this).remove();
}
```

I've been programming all day so my brain is fried, I'm sure there's something very simple I'm overlooking. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex matching table rows in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289181/regex-matching-table-rows-in-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a slight nuance of what null suggested will remove the entire row:

```
$('tr > td:nth-child(3):contains("$")').parent().remove();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kp5r/)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you could use [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), in this case:

```
$('tr > td:nth-child(3):contains("$")').remove();
```

Comment: good call, didn't even think about contains. However this removes the column, not the row. It should be `$('tr > td:nth-child(3):contains("$")').parent('tr').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

The `match` method returns an array. You want to use the `test` method instead.

```
$('tr').filter(function() {
    return /\$/.test( $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text() );
})
.remove();
```